# Is there any difference between 'based on' and 'on the basis of'?

Tags: phrases

Are 'on the basis' and 'based on' exchangeable? For example, can I speak
 this sentence

> His article was written **on the basis of** earlier accounts of reference frames.

as the same as another

> His article was written **based on** earlier accounts of reference frames.

Comment: edit to "on the basis of" not on the basis

Comment: See also: [*“based on” usage* - English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231123/based-on-usage)

Answer (score 3):

They mean the same thing but syntactically they're not interchangeable. "Based on" modifies a noun; "on the basis of" modifies a verb:

> Their *conclusions* **were based on** their analysis of three sets of data.
>
> We *accepted* their conclusions **on the basis of** their research.

Answer (score 2):

A **basis** is reasons or justifications for making a logical argument.
**On the basis of** is used to reference those reasons.

> **On the basis of** the General Theory of Relativity, gravity ripples were discovered.

**Based on** is used to refer to an account, description, or experience of *something*

> The movie was **based on** a true story.

Comment: Is "based on the basis of" acceptable as well in a sentence? E.g. "Sadly, he was expelled from the school based on the basis of rumors circulated about him."

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in meaning: "based on" and "on the basis of" are interchangeable. However, the use of "on the basis of" sounds better in the sentence.

You can also say:

> Based on earlier accounts' reference frames, his article was written.

Comment: I don't think that comma should be there, but it's hard to say for sure when your example ends with an ellipsis.

Comment: J.R. Thanks for your comments. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

**Based on** modifies the subject of the main clause of the sentence.

> **Based on** the test scores, Scott selected the top candidates.

This is incorrect because it makes it sound as if Scott (the subject) is based on the test scores. 
This could be rewritten as:

> **On the basis of** the test scores, Scott selected the top candidates.

or

> Scott selected the top candidates **on the basis of** their test scores.

**On the basis of** modifies the main verb of the sentence.

> **On the basis of** the test scores, Scott selected the top candidates.

This is correct because the test scores were used to make the selection.